# Populating an even distribution of values across multiple axis?

Tags: distributions, python, experiment-design, permutation

I'm trying to design an experiment with:

- `x` number of people
- `y` number of tasks
- `z` number of methods

The outcome I'm looking for is statistically reliable data comparing the time taken by each `method`, while ***minimizing*** the impact of ***who*** (`person`) did the task, or ***what*** (`task`) was being done. Each `person` *should* be approximately the same speed, but each `task` will take take different amounts of time. I'll probably use Multiple T-Tests for the analysis.

For example, with:

- 4 people
- 8 tasks
- 4 methods

A 'good' distribution would look like:

```
       col0  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7
row_0     0     1     2     3     0     1     2     3
row_1     1     2     3     0     1     2     3     0
row_2     2     3     0     1     2     3     0     1
row_3     3     0     1     2     3     0     1     2
```

Where:

- Every column has the same count of each task
- Every row has the same count of each task

I feel like this can't be a unique problem... I'm just not sure what to search for to describe this type of problem.

---

This is what I've attempted so far:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

def create_df(cols, rows, n):
    x = itertools.cycle(list(itertools.permutations(range(n))))
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(rows), columns=range(cols))
    df[:] = np.reshape([next(x) for _ in range((rows*cols)//n)], (rows, cols))
    #df = df.T.add_prefix('row_').T
    #df = df.add_prefix('col_')
    return df 

params = {
    'cols': 8,
    'rows': 4, 
    'n': 4
}
df = create_df(**params)
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
0  0  1  2  3  0  1  3  2
1  0  2  1  3  0  2  3  1
2  0  3  1  2  0  3  2  1
3  1  0  2  3  1  0  3  2

# Correct on this Axis:
>>> df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(), axis=1)
   0  1  2  3
0  2  2  2  2
1  2  2  2  2
2  2  2  2  2
3  2  2  2  2

# Incorrect on this Axis:
>>> df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts())
     0  1    2    3    4  5    6    7
0  3.0  1  NaN  NaN  3.0  1  NaN  NaN
1  1.0  1  2.0  NaN  1.0  1  NaN  2.0
2  NaN  1  2.0  1.0  NaN  1  1.0  2.0
3  NaN  1  NaN  3.0  NaN  1  3.0  NaN
```

Comment: Looks like a randomize block design.

Comment: Without additional criteria, there are often hordes of solutions.  In fact, Fisher's Exact Test employs the hypergeometric distribution of all those solutions.

Comment: @whuber I added some information about my desired outcome variable.

Comment: Thank you.  But because data don't compare anything and "statistically reliable" and "impact" are undefined and therefore meaningless, it's difficult to see what those criteria add.

Comment: I do not know what you are looking for or trying to prove. I already know you are superior in this area of expertise, your non-answers and randomly bringing up a completely non-applicable test have been less than helpful. What part of *experiment design* do you not understand? I'm not looking to analyze this matrix of numbers... I'm looking to create it and was hoping for worthwhile feedback on whether or not designing an experiment with this framework would be help *lead* to useful analysis.